# How to reference packages from repository in Flutter?

Tags: git, flutter, package, pubspec

I'm trying to modify an existing package on pub.dev. I need to update one of the dependencies in the package. I've seen how to do this from [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-modify-an-existing-pub-package-to-use-in-your-flutter-project-4e909452ee66)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  graphql_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/username/graphql-flutter.git
```

When I run `flutter pub get`
I get `pub get failed (1; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml"`

Looking at the [repository](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter)

There is no `pubspec.yaml` in the root

I presume I need to reference the `pubspec.yaml` in the packages folder? There is 2 of them there...
Not sure how to do this?

The package is [graphql_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because that's a repo with multiple packages. You need to reference the path and branch directly, just like so, for example for the `master` branch:

```
graphql_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter.git
      ref: master
      path: packages/graphql_flutter
```

If you want both packages:

```
graphql_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter.git
      ref: master
      path: packages/graphql_flutter

graphql:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter.git
      ref: master
      path: packages/graphql
```

Comment: cheers, how would add the 2 paths for the 2 packages?